# Angular Material button style only gets applied in app.component

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I recently switched over to a custom Material theme, but it came to my attention that everything gets the right theme, except the buttons in my components.

The button works without any problems, as do the other elements in my component.
Adding`color="primary"` changes the color of the text, but thats all it does.
Since the mat-toggle works as supposed, I don't think it has anything to do with missing imports (MatButtonModule is imported)

Below is a picture of my button and the most important code of the html file:

[image: Button without theme]

**html**

```html
<h3>Recent Quiz Participants ({{participants.length}})</h3>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="filterbar">
    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Displayed Columns</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeColumns($event)" [formControl]="columns" multiple>
        <mat-select-trigger>
          {{columns.value ? columns.value[0] : ''}}
          <span *ngIf="columns.value?.length > 1" class="additional-selection">
            (+{{columns.value.length - 1}} {{columns.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
          </span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let column of selectedColumns" [value]="column">{{column}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Download</button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <mat-slide-toggle (change)="completedOnly = !completedOnly" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">Completed only
      </mat-slide-toggle>
      <button (click)="onClickCsv()" mat-menu-item>CSV</button>
      <button (click)="onClickJson()" mat-menu-item>JSON</button>
      <button (click)="onClickXlsx()" mat-menu-item>XLSX</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
@import'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';

.additional-selection {
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-nocontent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.filterbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}


.form-wrapper,
mat-form-field,
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
}

mat-table {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.spinner-card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}

mat-row, mat-header-row, mat-footer-row {
  padding-left: 24px;
  padding-right: 24px;
}

mat-cell:first-child, mat-footer-cell:first-child, mat-header-cell:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

mat-cell:last-child, mat-footer-cell:last-child, mat-header-cell:last-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

mat-slide-toggle{
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

**Theme**

```css
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$custom-theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-orange, 700);
$custom-theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$custom-theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red, 50);

$custom-theme: mat-light-theme($custom-theme-primary, $custom-theme-accent, $custom-theme-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($custom-theme);
```

Comment: did you include the stylesheet in the angular.json file ?

Comment: @saidutt Yes, since all my other material elements work fine, just the button doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was misinterpreting mat-button. To get the background color on a button, you need mat-flat-button or mat-raised-button.

Comment: Thank you! That was my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

`mat-button` and `mat-menu-item` are 2 different things. Here is a modified Materials example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9kpiri

Notice that on the first element I'm trying to do what you're describing. The third element, however, is just using `mat-button` and is listening to the `color` property.

Comment: But shouldn't the button which activates the menu have some sort of background by default? As far as I'm aware, the default themes give those buttons a background, while my theme doesnt for some reason

Answer (score 0):

for Toggle button you need to import "import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';" After that you can use it's futher properties. for more reference click on the following link:
https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api

you have used slidetoggle for that you need to import "import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';" instead of above i have mentioned.